# Amazon DynamoDB updateTable SerializationException error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, expression, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update one of my secondary indexes in my DB but I am getting the following error

```
'Error executing "UpdateTable" on "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: 400 SerializationException (client): Start of structure or map found where not expected. - {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException","Message":"Start of structure or map found where not expected."}' exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: 400' in _aws/3.3.0/GuzzleHttp/Middleware.php:69 Stack trace: #0
```

and no matter where I look I cannot find anything on `SerializationException` errors. Here is my array set up

```
Array
(
    [TableName] => usuarios
    [GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates] => Array
        (
            [Update] => Array
                (
                    [IndexName] => nombre-creado-index
                    [ProvisionedThroughput] => Array
                        (
                            [ReadCapacityUnits] => 50
                            [WriteCapacityUnits] => 50
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and not matter what I try I cannot see where the error stands. I can query and update the tables without any issue. I can also run `describeTable` and get all table content with no problem. Any ideas where I could be having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the array, an associative array, not the procedure, here is the correct set up

```
Array
(
    [TableName] => usuarios
    [GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Update] => Array
                        (
                            [IndexName] => nombre-creado-index
                            [ProvisionedThroughput] => Array
                                (
                                    [ReadCapacityUnits] => 50
                                    [WriteCapacityUnits] => 50
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```